Deployment on Google App Engine Failing After Laravel Upgrade
I'm trying to deploy a Laravel project from GIT to my Google App Engine.
I had to upgrade to Laravel 8 because Google no longer accepted builds with outdated versions of Laravel and PHP (less than 8.1).
Unfortunately, since I performed the upgrade, the deployment fails with an error that I can't understand:
ERROR: failed to build: exit status 1

And more specifically, I get this error:
Step #2 - "build": Script php artisan package
--ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 255
ERROR: build step 2 "eu.gcr.io/serverless-runtimes/google-18-full/builder/php
" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 51

Can anyone give me some advice on how to resolve this issue?
Thanks in advance.

This might help you with error 51

maybe im not understanding but im not using node
